# I am trying to update profile and status if its their own profile and status. But the user is able to update others profile and status

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Thank you guys all in advance. Hoping for a soon response.

**permission.py**

```
class UpdateRegister(permissions.BasePermission):
    """ Allow user to edit their own profile. """

    def has_object_permissions(self, request, view, obj):
        """ Check user is trying to edit their own profile. """

        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.id == request.user.id


class PostOwnStatus(permissions.BasePermission):
    """ Allow user to update their own status. """

    def has_object_permissions(self, request, view, obj):
        """ Check user is trying to update their own status. """

        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.user_profile.id == request.user.id
```

This is the permission.py file where users are allow to edit or update their own profile and status.

**view.py*

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited. """

    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = UserRegister.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateRegister,)

class ProfileFeedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ Handles creating reading and updating profile feed. """

    serializer_class = ProfileFeedSerializer
    queryset = ProfileFeed.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.PostOwnStatus, IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Sets the user profile to the logged in user."""

        serializer.save(user_profile=self.request.user)
```

This is view.py file. Here i have got user view set and profile feed view set

**serializer.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserRegister
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """ Create and return a new user"""

        user = UserRegister(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            name=validated_data['name'],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user

class ProfileFeedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
""" Serialzer for profile feed. """

    class Meta:
     model = ProfileFeed
     fields = ('id', 'user_profile', 'post', 'created_on')
     extra_kwargs = {'user_profile': {'read_only':True}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your permission class methods are returning True before matching the user. Try changing the condition into this:

```
if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS and obj.id == request.user.id:
    return True
```

Comment: Can you debug to see what are the values of **obj.id** and **request.user.id**? Are they same of different?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, you do not need to add custom permission classes for this.

You can remove `permission_classes` from your ViewSets. Instead, override `get_permissions()` and define permissions conditionally in your viewsets:

```
def get_permissions(self):

    pk = self.kwargs['pk'] if 'pk' in self.kwargs else ''
    is_myself = self.request and self.request.user and pk == str(
            self.request.user.id)

    # define your own logic here
    if is_myself and self.action != 'destroy':
        permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    elif (self.action == 'list' or self.action == 'retrieve'):
        permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    else:
        permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]
    return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

You might want to write those conditions according to your need.

[See DRF's api guide](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#introspecting-viewset-actions)